# samba, изменить время модификации файла после копирования в шару

Tags: linux, samba

Есть ресурс на samba, на который пользователи копируют файлы (более 100 000 штук, большой размер). Все файлы с помощью rsync улетают на другой ресурс. Проблема в следующем: если пользователь заменит в шаре файл старой версией, она не улетает на другой ресурс. Знаю что rsync умеет сравнивать файлы по хэшу, но это слишком ресурсоемкий процесс...
Может есть в samba параметр который изменит время модификации файла после копирования в шару?

Comment: rsync -vrhu ./from/ srv::to/ ?

Comment: что это меняет? тогда уж --size-only

Comment: ключ `-u` копирует тока те файлы, которые изменились, а не всё подряд. Скорость возрастает достаточно сильно.

Comment: у меня складывается впечатление что вы не читали проблему.

Comment: Перечитал. Не. Вроде всё верно понял. Ключ `-u` не смотрит на хэш. Он смотрит на время изменения файла.

Comment: [don Rumata](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191416/don-rumata), не подходит такой вариант. По прежнему у меня файлы не обновляются. Уже сделал костыль, всем файлам сделал другого владельца, `find` прохожу все файлы у которых владелец не спец.юзер, и делаю им touch и меняю владельца. Таким образом удается добиться нужного результата и файлы всегда обновляются.

Comment: Хм... а может попробвать `syncthing`?